# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que un formulario primero ejecute una validación y después realice el proceso php?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Necesito que un formulario que cree  valide si unos ciertos campos están completados, pero no sé si se debe usar un botón para enviar los formularios o un input-submit. Además de esto cuando le doy al botón se ejecuta el código PHP que envía  los datos a la base de datos sin validar lo que escribí en JAVASCRIPT.

```js
function validar(){
 let nombre= document.getELementsByClassName('input')[0,1,2,3].value;
 if (nombre==0) {
  alert("hay campos vacios");
 }else{
  alert("1");
 }

}
```

```css
<?php
include "conectar.php";
$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
$apellido=$_POST["apellido"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$contraseña=$_POST["contraseña"];

$evaluacion="INSERT INTO multas(nombre, apellido, email, clave) VALUES('$nombre', '$apellido', '$email', '$contraseña')";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $evaluacion);

?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title>Blank App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    </head>
 <body>  
  <div class="contenedor">
   <div class="contenedor_botones_inicio">
   <button class="boton_inicio" id="boton_inicio1" onclick="saludo()">registrate</button><button class="boton_inicio" id="boton_inicio2">Ingresa</button>
</div>
  <form action="procesar.php" method="post">
    <h3>Registrate gratis</h3>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Primer nombre*" class="texto" id="texto1" name="nombre">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Segundo nombre*" class="texto" id="texto2" name="apellido"><br>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email*" class="texto" id="texto3" name="email"><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña*" class="texto" id="texto4" name="contraseña"><br>
    <button class="boton_enviar" onclick="validar()"></button>
  </form>
</div>
        <script src="comando.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No te entiendo.

Comment: Lo normal sería utilizar AJAX junto a JQuery. Pero también se puede utilizar solo javascript sin AJAX. Lo primero necesitas desactivar el submit con `event.preventDefault()` y luego volver a enviar el evento de submit

Comment: Una pregunta, listo utilizo esas herramientas y después cuando convierta el código en una APP mediante phonegap estos procesos de validación se van a seguir realizando?

Comment: Si, sigue siendo html, css y javascript. JQuery es como una especie de atajo de javascript. Por ejemplo algo que te puede costar 5-6 lineas te lo resume en una linea. Aunque como en la web, tienes que importar el script con una etiqueta `<script>` externa

Answer (score 0):

pude solucionar esta pregunta de este modo:le puse el atributo onsubmit="return validar()" a el form luego de esto le agregue algunas cositas al código JAVASCRIPT, ahora quiero saber si es un buena práctica y quiero saber si es mejor hacer este proceso o validar mediante AJAX y JQuery.

```js
function validar(){
 let nombre, apellido, email, contraseña;
 nombre=document.getElementById("texto1").value;
 apellido=document.getElementById("texto2").value;
 email=document.getElementById("texto3").value;
 contraseña=document.getElementById("texto4").value;
 if (nombre==="") {
  alert("hay campos vacios");
  return false;
 }else{
  alert("1");
 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title>Blank App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    </head>
 <body>  
          <script src="comando.js"></script>
  <div class="contenedor">
   <div class="contenedor_botones_inicio">
   <button class="boton_inicio" id="boton_inicio1" onclick="saludo()">registrate</button><button class="boton_inicio" id="boton_inicio2">Ingresa</button>
</div>
  <form action="procesar.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validar()">
    <h3>Registrate gratis</h3>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Primer nombre*" class="texto" id="texto1" name="nombre">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Segundo nombre*" class="texto" id="texto2" name="apellido"><br>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email*" class="texto" id="texto3" name="email"><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña*" class="texto" id="texto4" name="contraseña"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="" class="boton_enviar">
  </form>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El JQuery se utiliza para el AJAX. El Ajax se utiliza para enviar los datos. Vamos, en vez de un `action="procesar.php"` es un `$.ajax(....`. Es una manera distinta de hacerlo ya que le puedes pasar datos "ocultos" sin añadir un `<input type="hidden">` o si quieres hacer que la página no se tenga que recargar y solo te salte un mensaje.